# How to allow users to comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'd like users to be able to comment. At the present moment anyone can comment just by typing in a arbitrary name in the name field.

But I'd like to associate a comment with a user. So there will no longer be a need for a name field in the comments form as it will be the users name.

How can this be done?

I've followed Ryan Bates railscast but he never associates comments with users.

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @comments = Comment.where("song_id IS NOT ?", nil)
  end

  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)    

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to song_url(@comment.song_id), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'  }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to song_url(@comment.song_id), notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
      redirect_to song_url(@comment.song_id)
    end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:song_id, :author_name, :site_url, :content, :user_id)
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :songs
  has_many :comments

  acts_as_voter

end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :song
end
```

**comments#form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


    <div id="comment_form">
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.hidden_field :song_id %>
      <p>
        <%= f.text_field :author_name, placeholder: "Name"  %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => '12', :cols => 35, placeholder: "Leave a comment..."  %>
      </p>
      <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
    <% end %>
    <br /><br />

    </div></div>
```

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34578/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-17984518-how-to-allow-users-to-comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Comment` table should have a column named `user_id` if it does not already.  Then you can assign the `user_id` two different ways.  These assume you have a `current_user` method.  If you do not, then you will have to fill in the user_id from whatever session store or method you are using.

You could create a hidden_field in your form to assign it.

`<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>`

but as noted by @rmagnum2002 this could be a security concern due to a user could edit this.

You could assign it during the create action:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to song_url(@comment.song_id), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'  }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment}
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Assigning this in the controller create action is probably best.

Comment: using hidden field is a risky thing as this field is editable in chrome inspector, better go with the controller check.

Comment: @magnum, you are correct.  I edited my answer to reflect this concern.

Comment: having trouble displaying the current_user email through the comment in the show action. I've tried comment.user_id.email with no luck =/

Comment: it should be comment.user.email, attribute user_id has no email.